# How to get the Router instance in initializer

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-router

I have a use-case where I want to register routes dynamically in an initializer.
Because the application is a self-defining app I don't know the routes at development time.

Currently I created an instance-initializer:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const myTempRouteList = ['home']; // this is retrieved from the backend

export function initialize(instance) {
  let container = instance.container;
  let router = container.lookup('router:main');

  myTempRouteList.forEach(function (name) {
    let routeName = name.dasherize();

    router.map(function(){ // router.map is undefined here
      this.resource(routeName, {path: routeName});
    });
    container.register(`route:${routeName}`, Ember.Route.extend({
    }));

  }, this);
}

export default {
  name: 'register-routes',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

The problem is that the router instance is present but is has no method `map`. In the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Router.html) it is described as a public method. Some other methods I checked are present, f.i. `hasRoute`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I had to call the `lookupFactory` method instead of the `lookup` method on the container.

```
export function initialize(instance) {
  let container = instance.container;
  let router = container.lookupFactory('router:main');

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who are working on latest ember with ember-cli (Ember > 2.0). This might be helpful

```
//initializer.js

export function initialize(application) {
    var routeNames = [];
    var router = application.__container__.lookupFactory('router:main');
    application.deferReadiness();

   //if you want to have your custom routes on the highest level
    if (routeNames.length > 0) {
        router.map(function() {
            var _this = this;
            routeNames.forEach(function(item,index) {
               _this.route(item);
            });
        });
    }

   //if you want to have your custom routes as a child of another parent route
    if (routeNames.length > 0) {
        router.map(function() {
            this.route('parentRoute', {path:'/'}, function(){
                var _this = this;
                routeNames.forEach(function(item,index) {
                    _this.route(item);
                });
            });
        });
    }

    application.advanceReadiness();
}
```